# VS Studio 2015 and management studio 2012

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

So I made a data on sql server manangement studio 2012. When I went to access that data in visual studio and gave me an error and told me I needed to upgrade database. Which it asked and I said yes. So I worked with the database a little and inserted a couple of cells from Visual studio and now when i log back over to management studio the database is stuck in recovery pending. Is there a way to fix this? This is localdb so the files and mdf.

Comment: You can try to reinstall the local db from your installation file.

Answer (score 0):

VS2015 is not the best suite for SSMS 2012, it will bring the compatible issue, for example, the integration service, etc. Switch to use VS2012, and if your database is in `Restoring` status for long time for small size database, most likely you did not use `With recovery` when you `Restore` the database because the database is waiting for the latest `Transaction Log`, you could try `Restore Database [YourDatabase] with Recovery`, and then refresh it, should be good.

**PS** :you could add `STATS` to track the progress just in case that database is still being restored.

Comment: I am unsure of where to get VS2012 VS 2015 was free(community) and everything I have used is on this one is VS2012 free now?

Comment: no comments..that is not related to technical issue

Comment: I figured out what is causing it. As soon as I Upgrade it the database is in recovery pending. It said it was not compatible with this sql server instance. Is it because I am using 2015? Is there a newer version of SSMS that is more compatible?

Comment: you cannot restore the database with `.bak` backed up from the other version of sql server, if the database currently in `Restoring`, try the method I post above. The `compatible level` is a different thing from `database version`

Comment: I am cofused by when you said switch to use VS2012 you mean install VS 2012?

Comment: @okadante, yes, you could try to access the database using VS2012

Comment: Before I try VS 2012. My SSMS 2012 is 64bit and my visual studio 2015 is 32bit could that cause the errors?